# How to delete the report generated by kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, report, kibana

How to delete the reports generated by kibana? (version i am using with elasticsearch is 6.8)

below is screenshot of the reports generated , but It seems I could only download them but not

delete them . Does anyone know how to delete them? Any hints or suggestiones are more than welcome!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ability to delete reports using the UI was added in Elasticsearch 7.7.
Check out  these discussions:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/delete-reports-from-reporting-tab-in-kibana/233458

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/automatically-remove-old-reports/321201

Answer (score 0):

In Elasticsearch v8:

1. Navigate to **Kibana menu** -> **Stack Management** -> **Index Lifecycle Policies**
2. Find and open `kibana-reporting`
3. In **Hot phase** choose `Delete data after this phase`
4. **Delete phase** should appear at the very end
5. Set the desired time period, e.g. 30 days, and save.

Also, you might need to enable `allow_restricted_indices` for the  Kibana user that is used to update ILM policy:

```bash
curl -X POST "es.your-domain.com:9200/_security/role/your_kibana_user" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -u username:password \
     -d '{
  "indices": [
    {
      "names": [".reporting*"],
      "privileges": ["all"],
      "allow_restricted_indices": true
    }
  ]
}'
```